# Faster ways to sort and append large dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I’m trying to sort some sales data per product day of sale and product ID, and then I would like to compute some statistics with pandas. Is there an efficient way to do this? My dataset has millions of rows.

The dataset looks like this (df1, 3.000.000 + rows): -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
|productID |productCategory |expiryDate |Price |Currency |quantitySold| daySold| 

|Fdgd4   |Ergdgf |15sep2020 00:00:00 |125 |USD |5675 |18feb2017 12:45:17| 
|Sd23454 |sdfdsr |17mar2018 00:00:00 |39  |USD |654  |31jan2017 12:45:17| 
|Fdgd4   |Ergdgf |15sep2020 00:00:00 |125 |USD |300  |18feb2017 09:17:15| 
|Sd23454 |sdfdsr |17mar2018 00:00:00 |39  |USD |200  |31jan2017 15:30:35| 
|Rt4564  |fdgdf  |13jun2018 00:00:00 |45  |USD |1544 |31feb2017 13:25:31| 
|Fdgd4   |Ergdgf |15sep2020 00:00:00 |125 |USD |4487 |18mar2017 09:17:15| 
|Sd23454 |sdfdsr |17mar2018 00:00:00 |39  |USD |7895 |31aug2017 15:30:35|
```

I would like to sort compute some simple statistics per productID, per day. So I think my code should first order the rows per day and then per product. Then it should compute the statistics and add them to the table.

The result in this example is(df2):

```
|productID |productCategory |expiryDate |Price |Currency |quantitySold |daySold |volSTD |totalVol |totalRevenue|
------------------------------------------------------------------------**

|Sd23454 |sdfdsr |17mar2018 00:00:00 39  |USD |654  |31jan2017 12:45:17 |321.02 |854   |33306  |
|Fdgd4   |Ergdgf |15sep2020 00:00:00 125 |USD |300  |31jan2017 15:30:35 |0      |300   |37500  |
|Fdgd4   |Ergdgf |15sep2020 00:00:00 125 |USD |5675 |18feb2017 12:45:17 |840.04 |10162 |1270250|
|Rt4564  |fdgdf  |13jun2018 00:00:00 45  |USD |1544 |31feb2017 13:25:31 |0      |544   |69480  |
|Sd23454 |sdfdsr |17mar2018 00:00:00 39  |USD |7895 |31aug2017 15:30:35 |0      |7895  |307905 |
```

I use a nested for loop in pandas which gives the expected result but it does take way to long (a couple of hours).
I am looking for a fast way to get this result.

My code (probably on of the worst you’ve ever seen):

```
uniqueDays = df1.daySold.unique()
numberOfDays = df1.shape[0]
df_results = pd.Dataframe(columns=[‘productID’, ‘productCategory’, ‘expiryDate  Price’, ‘Currency’, ‘quantitySold’, ‘daySold’, ‘volSTD’, ‘totalVol’, ‘totalRevenue’])
For i in range(0, numberOfDays):
    temp1 = df1.loc[df1[‘daySold’]== uniqueDays[i]]
    uniqueID = temp1.productID.unique()
    NumberOfUniqueID = uniqueID.shape[0]
    for j in range(0, NumberOfUniqueID):
        temp2 = temp1.loc[temp1[‘daySold’]== uniqueID[j]
        volSTD = temp2.quantitySold.std()
        totalVol = temp2.quantitySold.sum()
        totalRevenue = temp2.quantitySold.dot(temp2.price)
        temp3 = temp2.iloc[0] # it does not matter which row I pick
        temp3[‘volSTD’] = volSTD
        temp3[‘totalVol’] = totalVol
        temp3[‘totalRevenue’] = totalRevenue
        df_results = df_results.append(temp3)
```

This gives me the results I want I want, but it is way too slow. In particular adding the columns (volSTD, totalVol and totalRevenue) to temp3 and appending temp3 to df_results take a combined 81.3% of the processing time.

Does anyone have a faster way to do this? Using vectors? Or filling an existing dataframe instead of appending?

Thanks

Comment: Have you looked at `groupby`? This sounds like a clear `groupby` workflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about `groupby`? It handles, so to speak, the iterations much more efficiently than loops and in much shorter and readable code. You would group on `daySold` and `productID`. This is obviously mock data, but you would want to turn your `daySold` into a `datetime` object first so you can easily group on it - I just kept the day, but you could keep the time if needed:

```
df.daySold=pd.to_datetime(df.daySold.apply(lambda x: x[:9]),format="%d%b%Y")
```

Then it is just a one-liner. With the `groupby` object you can pass a number of different aggregation calls.

```
df.groupby(['daySold','productID']).agg({'quantitySold':[sum,np.std],'Price':[sum,np.std]})

                     quantitySold              Price     
                              sum          std   sum  std
daySold    productID                                     
2017-01-31 Sd23454            854   321.026479    78  0.0
2017-02-13 Rt4564            1544          NaN    45  NaN
2017-02-18 Fdgd4             5975  3800.698949   250  0.0
2017-03-18 Fdgd4             4487          NaN   125  NaN
2017-08-30 Sd23454           7895          NaN    39  NaN
```

EDIT:

You can use the groupby object to apply all manner of functions, off the shelf ones and ones you define yourself.

So you could do a dot product, requiring *two* columns / arrays of a dataframe, like so:

```
def dotter(df):
    return np.sum(df.quantitySold*df.Price)
    ## or if you want to use numpy--may be faster for large datasets:
    #return np.dot(df.quantitySold,df.Price)
```

Call it by using apply method of groupby object:

```
 df.groupby(['daySold','productID']).apply(dotter)

daySold     productID
2017-01-31  Sd23454       33306
2017-02-13  Rt4564        69480
2017-02-18  Fdgd4        746875
2017-03-18  Fdgd4        560875
2017-08-30  Sd23454      307905
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thanks, your solution is way faster. Only How do I compute the dot multiplication between price and quantitySold in the groupby? And how do I return the other columns(productID |productCategory |expiryDate |Price |Currency |quantitySold | daySold ) ? I only get the sum and std. Thanks

Comment: As to your second question - if those other columns vary uniquely with productID, you could just add them to the `groupby()` clause, then they will be a part of the `MultiIndex`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was writing to csv with index=False, not realizing that the missing columns were actually the index. One last detail: is it possible to call the dotter function in agg()? If not I will just have to join both dataframes.
Thanks again