# groupby pivot KeyError

Tags: pandas, pivot, pandas-groupby

This is an extension to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46985022/faster-ways-to-sort-and-append-large-dataframe/46985435#46985435) question; I am now trying to hae all the descriptive statistics instead of just the sum and standard deviation.

I tried this code from this answer from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33575587/pandas-dataframe-how-to-apply-describe-to-each-group-and-add-to-new-columns) question:

```
df = grouped.describe().reset_index().pivot(index=index_columns, values=’price’, columns=’level_1’)
```

and I get this error:

```
KeyError: ‘level_1’
```

index_columns = ['daySold','productID']

grouped = df.groupby(index_columns)

Does anyone knows what I’m doing wrong?

here is the data:

```
|productID |productCategory |expiryDate |Price |Currency |quantitySold| daySold| 

|Fdgd4   |Ergdgf |15sep2020 00:00:00 |125 |USD |5675 |18feb2017 12:45:17| 
|Sd23454 |sdfdsr |17mar2018 00:00:00 |39  |USD |654  |31jan2017 12:45:17| 
|Fdgd4   |Ergdgf |15sep2020 00:00:00 |125 |USD |300  |18feb2017 09:17:15| 
|Sd23454 |sdfdsr |17mar2018 00:00:00 |39  |USD |200  |31jan2017 15:30:35| 
|Rt4564  |fdgdf  |13jun2018 00:00:00 |45  |USD |1544 |31feb2017 13:25:31| 
|Fdgd4   |Ergdgf |15sep2020 00:00:00 |125 |USD |4487 |18mar2017 09:17:15| 
|Sd23454 |sdfdsr |17mar2018 00:00:00 |39  |USD |7895 |31aug2017 15:30:35|
```

Thanks

Comment: `Does anyone knows what I’m doing wrong?` What's wrong is you haven't provided your data or expected output, so there's no way for us to know what you're even trying to do. All the best I guess.

Comment: Sorry about that, see my edit: this an extension to a question I asked before; now I am trying to get all the descriptive stats instead of the wo mentioned in it. np.stats.describe or just describe do not seem to work here.

Comment: Can you copy the data over into this question? It's best to keep each question self sufficient rather than keep many references to others.

Comment: Ok. I just added it

Comment: Your column names in `index_columns` are different but?

Comment: Yes, in this example it's ['daySold','productID']. I edited the question

Comment: `df.groupby(index_columns).describe()` seems to work for me.

Comment: You're right; I'm going to review my code as it looks like I mad a mistake somewhere else. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It's just because you don't have the column level_1. Look at the output of

```
df = grouped.describe().reset_index()
df
                daySold productID **level_2**  Price  quantitySold
0   18feb2017 09:17:15   Fdgd4      count    1.0           1.0
1   18feb2017 09:17:15   Fdgd4       mean  125.0         300.0
2   18feb2017 09:17:15   Fdgd4        std    NaN           NaN
3   18feb2017 09:17:15   Fdgd4        min  125.0         300.0
4   18feb2017 09:17:15   Fdgd4        25%  125.0         300.0
5   18feb2017 09:17:15   Fdgd4        50%  125.0         300.0
6   18feb2017 09:17:15   Fdgd4        75%  125.0         300.0
7   18feb2017 09:17:15   Fdgd4        max  125.0         300.0
```

But then you will have another problem.

```
ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 56, placement implies 2
```

Just do :

```
df = grouped.describe().unstack(2)
print(df)



Price                                         \
                              count   mean std    min    25%    50%    75%   
daySold             productID                                                
18feb2017 09:17:15  Fdgd4       1.0  125.0 NaN  125.0  125.0  125.0  125.0   
18feb2017 12:45:17  Fdgd4       1.0  125.0 NaN  125.0  125.0  125.0  125.0   
18mar2017 09:17:15  Fdgd4       1.0  125.0 NaN  125.0  125.0  125.0  125.0   
31aug2017 15:30:35  Sd23454     1.0   39.0 NaN   39.0   39.0   39.0   39.0   
31feb2017 13:25:31  Rt4564      1.0   45.0 NaN   45.0   45.0   45.0   45.0   
31jan2017 12:45:17  Sd23454     1.0   39.0 NaN   39.0   39.0   39.0   39.0   
31jan2017 15:30:35  Sd23454     1.0   39.0 NaN   39.0   39.0   39.0   39.0
```